# Show that holomorphic function $f$ by condition $u_{n}=\frac{f\left(w_{n+1}\right)-f\left(w_{n}\right)}{w_{n+1}-w_{n}}$ has $\lim u_{n}=f^{'}(0)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ and $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. Complex pairs of different numbers  $w_{1}, w_{2}, w_{3}, \ldots$ belong to $D$ and $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} w_{n}=0$ For $n=1,2,3, \ldots$ Let
$$
u_{n}=\frac{f\left(w_{n+1}\right)-f\left(w_{n}\right)}{w_{n+1}-w_{n}}
$$
Show that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} u_{n}=f^{\prime}(0)$

We have Taylor for $f(w_n) - f(w_{n+1})= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_mw_n^{m} - \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_m w_{n+1}^{m}$
And we have 
$f^{\prime}(0) = a_1$

using $a^{n} - b^{n} = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + \ldots + b^{n-1})$ expression we have proof. It's correct thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is hard to justify since there is an infinte sum. Instead, you can write $\frac {f(w_{n+1})-f(w_n)} {w_{n+1}-w_n}$ as $\frac 1 {w_{n+1}-w_n}\int_{w_n}^{w_{n+1}} f'(\zeta) d\zeta$. So what you have to show is equivalent to showing that $\frac 1 {w_{n+1}-w_n}\int_{w_n}^{w_{n+1}} [f'(\zeta)-f'(0)] d\zeta \to 0$ and this is easy since $f'(\zeta) \to f'(0)$ as $ \zeta \to 0$.

Notation: $\int_a^{b} g(w)dw$ stands for the integral of $g$ over the line segment from $a$ to $b$.